# iOS 6 javascript intermittent issues with object.defineProperty

Tags: javascript, ios6

Has anyone else noticed intermittent errors/issues in the new iOS 6 javascript engine when accessing properties on objects where the property was defined using newer Object.defineProperty syntax?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

I'm seeing occasions where the javascript will fail stating undefined is not a function on methods of objects accessied as properties on objects defined in this manner.

Comment: proof ? jsfiddle example would be great.

Comment: There's a team here where I work who are working on an HTML5/Javascript app that is targeting Safari on an iPad. They mentioned a similar-sounding problem after upgrading a test iPad to iOS6. If I can track down an answer, I'll add it here. Good luck.

Comment: @Eric I've managed to "solve" the problem by removing all instances of JavaScript Object notation; Object.create, .defineProperty, and .seal. Still no idea on the root cause, and it's especially difficult to track down since I can reproduce the error in my app 100% of the time, and then when I connect to a MacBook to use the new Web Inspector, the problem stops happening. I was also unable to reproduce anything in isolation (i.e. jsFiddle), further adding to the frustration.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Kangax's ES5 table](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/), "In some versions of WebKit Object.defineProperty does not work with DOM objects." I'm assuming this is what you may be referring to. It's note #2 at the bottom of the page. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't already solved this, make sure the said property is enumerable (and if necessary configurable)...

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, "key", {
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true
});
```